# Set max weight per cart item in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, cart, hook-woocommerce

How can I set the maximum weight per product (not per order)?

The customer can buy any number (quantity) of products until the max weight is reached. If he buys 5 products, The weight of total unit of each product cant reach max weight. There can be many products in an order but Total units(quantity) per product has Max weight.

For example, In a single order:

- 3 units of product A (weighing total 2kg)
- 5 units of product B (weighing total 1.4kg)
- 3 units of product C (weighing total 2kg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example, the hooked function is triggered on add to cart action and you can perform all kind of checks to validate or not the action *(and display a custom error message)*.

So you will see that you can target the total item weight individually…

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_add_to_cart_validation', 20, 5 );
function custom_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations = '' ) {
    // HERE define the weight limit per item
    $weight_limit = 2; // 2kg

    $total_item_weight = 0;

    // Check cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $item_product_id = empty($variation_id) ? $product_id : $variation_id;

        // If the product is already in cart
        if( $item_product_id == $cart_item['data']->get_id() ){
            // Get total cart item weight
            $total_item_weight += $cart_item['data']->get_weight() * $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = empty($variation_id) ? wc_get_product($product_id) : wc_get_product($variation_id);

    // Get total item weight
    $total_item_weight += $product->get_weight() * $quantity;

    if( $total_item_weight > $weight_limit ){
        $passed = false ;
        $message = __( "Custom warning message for weight exceed", "woocommerce" );
        wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

You will need also  an additional hooked function that will be triggered on cart item quantity change:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'limit_cart_item_quantity', 20, 4 );
function limit_cart_item_quantity( $cart_item_key, $new_quantity, $old_quantity, $cart ){
    // HERE define the weight limit per item
    $weight_limit = 2; // 2kg
    
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = $cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['data'];
    
    $product_weight = $product->get_weight(); // The product weight
    
    // Calculate the limit allowed max quantity from allowed weight limit
    $max_quantity = floor( $weight_limit / $product_weight );
    
    // If the new quantity exceed the weight limit
    if( ( $new_quantity * $product_weight ) > $weight_limit ){
        
        // Change the quantity to the limit allowed max quantity
        $cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['quantity'] = $max_quantity;
        
        // Add a custom notice
        $message = __( "Custom warning message for weight exceed", "woocommerce" );
        wc_add_notice( $message, 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: THAK U VERY VERY MUCH. I also found that if I increase the quantity on cart page, it shows me that warning message and switch back to earlier quantity, which is in a way forcing buyer to stay within the limit and I like it.

Comment: But if I do the same on single product page, i.e. Assuming 2 different products weigh 2kg with 5 units total, now if I add Product A (3 units), it redirects me to cart page and then if I add Product B (3 units - exceeding weight!), instead of showing that warning message again,it just redirects me to cart page (with only the previous products added).It shud show the warning message on single product page that I cant exceed weight>2kg and stop the redirection to cart page.
My weight is also set to Pound (Ib), not in kg,wud u plz fix that.

Comment: I was trying to update custom Meta Data for each of my cart items and 2 things helped me immensely. They are: 1) The filter:  `add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'limit_cart_item_quantity', 20, 4 );` and 2) The way to update the Cart data: `$cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['quantity'] = $max_quantity;`. Thanks a TON for sharing!

Comment: Hi @loictheaztec, I tried this solution it works fine. I just faced an error. `wc_add_notice( $message, 'notice' )` is not showing any notice on the card page. In fact, it changes quantity to the maximum allowed, and then the notice says: Cart updated. Is there any way to change the notice to another message?